# Обновление div в AJAX без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, как в AJAX jQuery, сделать обновление одного конкретного `<div>`, без перезагрузки страницы:

```
    <div id="comments">
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   </div>

 $("#form").submit(function () {


//ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'keepComment.php',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {


                $('#comments').html(data);
            }

        });

            });
```

В общем по коду видно, что посылаю я `submit();` и мне нужно чтобы во время посылки `submit();`, автоматически обновлялся `<div>`.
Как такое можно сделать?
В функции заворачивал, `setInterval();` вызывал и т.д., что-то не катит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обработчик должен возвращать `false`, чтобы отменить стандартное поведение отправки формы на сервер и перезагрузки страницы.

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'keepComment.php',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      $('#comments').html(data);
      // или
      $('#comments').html(append);
    }
  });
  return false; // !!!
});
```

Comment: У меня записи исчезают до обновление страницы , которые ранее с бд вывел, не думаю, что это универсальное решение

Comment: Не сомневайтесь. Это - универсальное (и правильное) решение.

Comment: @Igor, правильно говорить "доверься мне"

Comment: @АлександрБелинский - не знал, спасибо. Завтра на панихиде скажу.

Comment: То что вы изменили содержание - так же плохой вариант. Ибо у меня там должно быть "название, комментарий,email". А через data получает  
все параметры. Разделять их еще по строчке, это уже костыльный код будет. Мне нужно именно, чтобы обновлялся div. А не при submit.

Comment: @nikitaAbramov - это что за поток сознания? Скажу без ложной скромности - это отличный ответ! Рекомендую им воспользоваться.

Comment: Вы когда людям работу выполняете, тоже им говорите "Не важно как Вы хотите, это отличное решение!". Просто не знаю, думал какое-то лучше решение будет. То таким способом я мог решить, и не задавая вопроса

Comment: @nikitaAbramov Прочитайте Ваш вопрос. А потом - комментарий. Телепаты - в отпуске. Ответ в точности соответствует вопросу. Хотите другой ответ - объясняйте, что Вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы страница не перезагружалась надо добавить прерывание действия.

```
// не забыть поставить у формы id="form"
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    // тут мы прерываем текущее действие
    e.preventDefault(e);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'keepComment.php',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#comments').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```