# Как вставить текст с jQuery (AJAX) в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, у меня вот такой HTML (CSS потом вынесу):

```
 <div id="comments" >
     <a style="color:black; font-size:19px; text-decoration:none" id="showName">
Имя</a>
    <p style="padding:10px; font-size:17px;" id="showComment">
Какой-то текст</p>
```

Как мне вставить с такими же параметрами в `<a>`, `<p>` новый текст через jQuery посредством AJAX, чтобы не перепрописывать к примеру через `.html()`.
Ну то есть, добавляю в бд и у меня сразу эти данные отображаются, а отображаю их через AJAX.
Вот как я предполагал:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'keepComment.php',
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                   //#name - id одной формы
               $("#comments").append($("#name").val()); //Вот как я пробывал
                    //$("#showComment").append(document.createTextNode($("#comment").val()));

                }
            });
            return false;
```

Comment: Что Вы пытаетесь сделать по success? Добавляете к элементу с id comments вэлью элемента с id name? Или это попытка ответ таким образом разобрать?

Comment: При success добавляет в бд (php), ну и мне нужно чтобы через js отобразилось сразу это, без обновления страницы. То есть я хочу чтобы через js создало элемент, и вставило
К примеру как в ютуб комментарии, отправляем, чуть грузится, и сразу отображает твой коммент.

Comment: Понял, смутило что функция с параметром. Так вы тут просто текст пытаетесь приаппендить, нужно элементы соответсвующие создать, заполнить и аппендить уже их. Тут даже ajax особо не причем к вопросу.

Comment: Это понятно, как это более грамотно сделать можно?

Comment: опять же непонятно вы хотите перезапись значения в уже существующих `<a>` и `<p>` или хотите дописать новые? В вашем коде есть неоднозначность...

Comment: создать новое хочу

Comment: @nikitaAbramov ага, значит `return false;` все-таки пригодилось

Answer (score 1):

Можно хоть так, но стили действительно лучше перенести) И `id` для каждого взятого комментария сомневаюсь, что нужны.

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var comment = $("#comment").val();
$("#comments").append(`<a style="color:black; font-size:19px; text-decoration:none">${name}</a>`);
$("#comments").append(`<p style="padding:10px; font-size:17px;">${comment}</p>`);
```

Comment: Есть какой-то более универсальный способ? Нежели пихать так все.
Писал же, что такое не подойдет

Comment: @nikitaAbramov в каком смысле "более универсальный"? Можно отдельным методом завести пустой тег, отдельным методом подцепить ему стиль и отдельным методом положить значение, но смысл от этого только эстетический (например через методы `.css()` и `.val()`

Comment: у ТС в голове есть какая-то идея "универсальности", которую он требует уже не в первый раз (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775265), но что эта "универсальность"  означает - не объясняет

Answer (score 0):

Я могу только догадываться, что Вам не нравится повторение html-a для тэгов `а` и `p` в коде. Это действительно не очень красиво.

Заведите на странице невидимый шаблон:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
  <a style="color:black; font-size:19px; text-decoration:none">Имя</a>
  <p style="padding:10px; font-size:17px;">Какой-то текст</p>
</div>
```

А в коде:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var comment = $("#comment").val();
var newItem = $($("#template").html());
newItem.find("a").text(name);
newItem.find("p").text(comment);
$("#comments").append(newItem);
```